# Converting RGB value into an integer pixel - Odd values occurring?

Tags: java, colors, bitmap, rgb

Before you say this is a duplicate question, hear me out. I've looked at the other questions, and I'm using (presumably) the correct method for getting the RGB values and storing it as an integer pixel.

My code:

```
// load pixels into an image
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(adjWidth, 
                                            this.height, 
                                            BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

    int iwidth = 0;
    int iheight = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < this.height; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < adjWidth - 2; j += 3) {
            int index = adjWidth*i + j;
            int b = iData[index];
            int g = iData[index+1];
            int r = iData[index+2];
            int rgb = ((r&0x0ff)<<16)|((g&0x0ff)<<8)|(b&0x0ff); // merge rgb values to single int
            int red = (rgb>>16)&0x0ff;
            int green =(rgb>>8) &0x0ff;
            int blue = (rgb)    &0x0ff;
            if(rgb != 0) {
                System.out.printf("\nRow: %s\nColumn: %s\nRed: %s\nGreen: %s\nBlue: %s\n", i, j, red, green, blue);
                System.out.println("Color value: " + rgb);
                image.setRGB(iwidth, iheight, rgb);
                iwidth++;
                iheight++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Where adjWidth is the width adjusted for padding, and iData is the byte array of the image data.
I looked at my output, and I see:

```
Row: 0
Column: 0
Red: 166
Green: 0
Blue: 0
Color value: 10878976
```

So the color value is obviously wrong (and throws an error when I use setRGB()), but why is this wrong?

Comment: It could be the difference between signed and unsigned bytes

Comment: I thought that the 0xff accounted for that? If not, how can I convert it to an unsigned byte?

Comment: I was thinking more of why `red` is `-90`, besides, I just use `Color(int, int, int)#getRGB` ;)

Comment: I know that red shouldn't be -90, but how can I convert that to an unsigned byte? Also, that function is helpful, but it basically just does the same thing I'm doing. Even then, it wouldn't accept a negative value, so my problem is converting those signed bytes to unsigned ints.

Comment: There is no way to accurately convert -90 to an unsigned byte, because an unsigned byte holds a value from 0 to 255, by definition. Not that it matters, since they don't exist in Java.

Comment: It's been a horrible long time since I've done anything like this, but I would assume that -90 would become 217 (+/-1), but `-90&0x0ff` seems to be generating 166...

Comment: @MadProgrammer 166 is the correct value of `(-90) & 255`. -90 is `...111110100110` and 166 is `...00010100110`.

Comment: Alright, so I'm doing that conversion to 166 in the col assignment. So why is that col some weird number?

Comment: Also @immibis I meant unsigned int, and I'm doing that in the col assignment anyway, so the question is moot.

Comment: Same thing. You can't have -90 in an unsigned int, and Java doesn't have unsigned ints anyway.

Comment: Also, I can't seem to tell what your actual question is (unless it's "this doesn't work, why doesn't it work?" in which case it's off-topic)

Comment: I got the correct values for the individual values now, look at my edited code. However, the rgb value itself is still messed up.

Comment: 166 x 65536 = 10878976, I don't see the problem.

Comment: Ok, I guess I didn't understand the rgb value set correctly. Thank you! Sorry for my stupidity. :(

Comment: 166 = 0xA6 
10878976  = 0xA60000
The thing you need to be careful of is the ordering of RGB in the integer.